# Rest Api - call custom rest api function

Tags: api, rest-api

i am beginner in creating Rest api, i dont know from where to start. till now am able to pull products list using `http://my_host.com/api/rest/products`. but am confused what will my url for calling custom function

Comment: Take a look here http://ctodilemma.com/2013/04/customising-and-extending-the-magento-rest-api/

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED:**

Tried this article ["How to Extend the Magento REST API to Use Coupon Auto Generation"](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-use-extend-the-magento-rest-api-to-use-coupon-auto-generation#test-run)

and with small tweak to call my custom method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Example of retrieving the products list using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
 * Preconditions:
 * 1. Install php oauth extension
 * 2. If you were authorized as a Customer before this step, clear browser cookies for 'yourhost'
 * 3. Create at least one product in Magento
 * 4. Configure resource permissions for Admin REST user for retrieving all product data for Admin
 * 5. Create a Consumer
 */
// $callbackUrl is a path to your file with OAuth authentication example for the Admin user

//Server global variables declarations
$baseUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$scriptName = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

$protocol = 'http://';
$callbackUrl = $protocol.$baseUrl.$scriptName;
//Variables for oAuth 1.0a
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = $protocol.$baseUrl."/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . $callbackUrl;
$adminAuthorizationUrl = $protocol.$baseUrl.'/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = $protocol.$baseUrl.'/oauth/token';
$resourceUrl = 'products';
$apiUrl = $protocol.$baseUrl.'/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'Your Consumer Key';
$consumerSecret = 'Your Consumer Secret';

if(isset($resourceUrl) && !empty($resourceUrl)) {
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
    }
    try {
        $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
        $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
        $oauthClient->enableDebug();

        if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
            $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
            $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
            header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
            exit;
        } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
            $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
            $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
            $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
            $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
            header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
            exit;
        } else {
            $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
            $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/$resourceUrl";
            $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
            $productsList = json_encode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
            echo $productsList;

        }
    } catch (OAuthException $e) {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
        echo "&lt;br/&gt;";
        print_r($e->lastResponse);
    }

} else {
    echo "Resource url is empty." . "<br />";
    echo  "Please enter resource url:" . "<br />";
    echo  "e.g. ?resource=products" . "<br />";
}`enter code here`
?>
```

Comment: You can also get resource url as a parameter in the link for making different rest api calls froma single PHP calling script: 
$resourceUrl = isset($_GET['resource']) ? $_GET['resource'] : NULL;

Comment: How to configure Magento REST and oAuth settings

Steps:

1. Creating oAuth Consumer

2. Creating and configuring Admin roles

3. Assigning configured Admin REST Role to admin user

4. Configuring resource attributes and access permissions

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxww_nvHTw3yMVdHTE5oUEdBRDg/view?usp=sharing